# .htaccess is erased always after a mysqld crash

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, centos6

I have the following strange (in my opinion) issue.

Whenever my MySQL server crashed, the current .htaccess file of my website has been erased.  All the .htaccess rules are gone. I have a complete empty .htaccess file with the same permissions of the old one.

That website is a WP - latest version of plugins/themes/WP

Any clue??

Also, I have tried every permission on the htaccess file, like 444, 655, 777, 755.  Everytime I got an empty .htaccess file when I restart the crashed mysqld service.

Also, **to be noticed**, that the VPS is Centos 6 and it hosts some more WP or custom HTML websites.
I have the .htaccess issue only with that WP. All the other WP or HTML websites are ok and their .htaccess are not edited/deleted/erased at all.

Comment: Revise you the permission `lsattr` yours .htaccess files if it has `----i--------e--` them you can execute `sudo chattr -i .htaccess`